# What is the meaning of !! in ReactJS / JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm new to react and I was reading about using transition and I stumbled on this [article](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/), which has few demo and saw this part of the code:

```
render() {
    const { show } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleToggle()}>
          Click to toggle
        </button>
        <div>
          <Fade in={!!show} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

What does it mean by two `!!`? It seems I can't find any docs about this symbol. I'm thinking this is a JSX syntax.

```
<Fade in={!!show} />
```

Comment: It's not React specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks! I didn't saw that answer through google or even in the title suggestions. Weird.